# What’s going on with these Haskell types?

Tags: haskell, types

Why does this function require a list of integers?

```hs
Prelude> :t \xs->[(map $ uncurry(*)) (zip xs [1..n]) | n<-[1..(length xs)]]
\xs->[(map $ uncurry(*)) (zip xs [1..n]) | n<-[1..(length xs)]]
  :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

When I replace `length xs` with a fixed value, the type changes and isn’t that strict anymore:

```hs
Prelude> :t \xs->[(map $ uncurry(*)) (zip xs [1..n]) | n<-[1..100]]
\xs->[(map $ uncurry(*)) (zip xs [1..n]) | n<-[1..100]]
  :: (Num b, Enum b) => [b] -> [[b]]
```

My compiler is

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` has type `Foldable t => t a -> Int`, which means `length xs` is specifically an `Int` value. That makes `[1..(length xs)]` be of type `[Int]`, etc.

`100`, on the other hand, is *not* an `Int` literal, but a polymorphic literal of type `Num a => a`. That makes `[1..100]` have type `Num a => [a]`, etc.

Which is to say, `length` is the only thing that's forcing a concrete type like `Int` in the final type. Replace that with the more general `100`, and the final type is more general as well.

Comment: So, if I understood, this boils down to that `(length [1,2,3]) * 4.5` isn’t possible in Haskell?

Comment: Not sure how this boils down to `(length [1,2,3]) * 4.5` being not possible. Haskell just requires you to explicitly convert `Int` to something with `Fractional a` constraint. `(fromIntegral $ length [1,2,3]) * 4.5` is totaly ok for compiler.

Comment: Thanks! `fromIntegral` looks very useful.

Comment: `(*)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. Both operands must have the same type, so no, `length [1,2,3] * 4.5` does not type check.

Comment: "Both operands must have the same type" OK, that was the point I had to learn.

Comment: Note that `Data.List` provides `genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i`, which provides the length using whatever `Num` instance you request.